# Make 2 Method with One (same parameter)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I think this is beginner stuff, but I still need to find a way to solve this.

I want to make the bool logic reference of the bool logar. The `invisiblearrow()`, I applied in toggle button in world space Unity thus I want to pass the logar to logic `bool.(same bool)`.

```cs
private void invisiblearrow(bool logar) {
    if (logar == false) {
        GameObject[] arrow = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("arrow");
        foreach(GameObject ar in arrow) {
            ar.GetComponent < Renderer > ().enabled = logar;
            Debug.Log(logar);
        }
    }
    if (logar == true) {
        GameObject[] arrow = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("arrow");
        foreach(GameObject ar in arrow) {
            ar.GetComponent < Renderer > ().enabled = logar;
            Debug.Log(logar);
        }
    }

}

public void arrow(float[, ] arrowdata, bool logic) {
    for (int x = 0; x < arrowdata.GetLength(0); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < arrowdata.GetLength(1); y++) {
            if (grid[x, y] == 1) {

                if (arrowdata[x, y] == 5) {
                    GameObject referenceArrow = Instantiate(Resources.Load("down")) as GameObject;
                    float posY = shipvalue.transform.position.y - 9f;
                    referenceArrow.transform.position = new Vector3(shipvalue.transform.position.x, posY);
                    referenceArrow.GetComponent < Renderer > ().enabled = logic;
                }
                if (arrowdata[x, y] == 4) {
                    GameObject referenceArrow = Instantiate(Resources.Load("top left")) as GameObject;
                    float posY = shipvalue.transform.position.y - 9f;
                    referenceArrow.transform.position = new Vector3(shipvalue.transform.position.x, posY);
                    referenceArrow.GetComponent < Renderer > ().enabled = logic;
                }
                if (arrowdata[x, y] == 3) {
                    GameObject referenceArrow = Instantiate(Resources.Load("top right")) as GameObject;
                    float posY = shipvalue.transform.position.y - 9f;
                    referenceArrow.transform.position = new Vector3(shipvalue.transform.position.x, posY);
                    referenceArrow.GetComponent < Renderer > ().enabled = logic;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to have `bool logic` with the same value in `bool logar`?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking exactly ... in the upper method you run quite redundant and could simply reduce the code to `private void invisiblearrow(bool logar) { GameObject[] arrow = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("arrow");  Debug.Log(logar); foreach (GameObject ar in arrow) { ar.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = logar; } }`

Comment: @loic.lopez yes..

Answer (score 1):

You can't because both bools are local bool (at the level of the function only), but you can:
Declare a private bool outside the two function (global), and at the end of `invisiblearrow(bool logar)` function, assign logar bool value to the new private bool (the new bool = logar), then you can access the new private bool in `arrow(float[,] arrowdata, bool logic)` function.